# Convert nested list into tree picture

Tags: json, tree, visualization

I have a JSON/Python nested list which represents a tree, each item being a node, if the node is a list, it is a subtree.

Any easy way to create some pleasing graphics out of that?

```
[[1, [[4, [[7], [8], [9]]], [5, [[7], [8], [9]]], [6, [[7], [8], [9]]]]], [2, [[4, [[7], [8], [9]]], [5, [[7], [8], [9]]], [6, [[7], [8], [9]]]]], [3, [[4, [[7], [8], [9]]], [5, [[7], [8], [9]]], [6, [[7], [8], [9]]]]]]
```

This is a neater layout of the [JSON itself](http://paste.ubuntu.com/706108), which does not help me too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) for making basic graph images using its simple dot notation. Then in python you could make a really simple recursive function that generates the dot file and builds the graph.

Comment: Yeah, that gives nice [results](http://wstaw.org/m/2011/10/11/tree.png). The fact that the nodes are "recycled" is obvious from the code. Thanks!